# Couchbase cannot access views while adding new documents

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

I'm using Cocuhbase Community Edition 6.0.0 build 1693 with below server config on a single node.

Total ram - 24GB
Data - 7608 MB
Index - 3255 MB
Search - 576 MB

With a Stale - OK and Update_After

```
ViewResult result =  bucket.query(ViewQuery.from(design, view)
        .key(id)
        .skip(skip)
        .limit(limit)
        .stale(Stale.UPDATE_AFTER));
List<T> ourDocs = new ArrayList<>();

result
   .iterator()
   .forEachRemaining(
        (doc) ->
                ourDocs.add(
                        fromJsonObject(doc.document().content(), type))
            );
```

While I create new documents from a C# TPL task. I cannot access the views, which was a similar issue with CouchDB.

Is there any other config Im missing here?

Comment: This was cross-posted to the discourse forum: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/cannot-access-view-while-adding-new-documents-to-couchbase-node/20004

Comment: Using Stale I could able to resolve the issue of getting docs from the updated view. The main cause is my bots are hitting API service (uses couchbase), which add new docs. By using NGINX load balance the API service I was able to resolve the issue and couchbase is really great in fast indexing the docs / updating views with Stale.UPDATE_AFTER.